# How to validate phone number

Tags: java

I am trying to validate phone numbers in java. In my country, phone numbers either begin with 9 or 8 and only have 8 numbers. I have done

```
try {
   Integer.parseInt(phoneNo);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)  {
    msg += "Plese enter amount in Integers.\n";
}
if (phoneNo.length() == 0)
   msg += "Please Enter Phone Number.\n";
if (phoneNo.length() != 8)
    msg += "Invalid Phone Number.\n";
```

However I need to validate when the first digit of the number isn't 9 or 8. I am not entirely sure of how I am supposed to do that. Please explain how your code works as I am a student and I am trying to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case you are looking for a regular expression solution.

You can do use the following pattern `^(?=(?:[8-9]){1})(?=[0-9]{8}).*` to perform the check.

Essentially what it does is;

1. From first character position `^`
2. Look ahead and see if the first character is a 8 or 9 `(?=(?:[8-9]){1})`
3. Then see if there are a total of 8 digits `(?=[0-9]{8})`
4. If the above conditions is a match then mark this as matched `.*`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String telephoneNr = "88765432";

    if (telephoneNr.matches("^(?=(?:[8-9]){1})(?=[0-9]{8}).*")) {
        System.out.println("Valid phone number!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Valid phone number!

Comment: You aren't using the validPattern variable. Shouldn't you just remove that declaration?

Comment: Also, up-voting for the use of regex which I always forget about ;-)

Comment: this does it as well: `"^[89]\\d{7}$"`

Comment: @P.J.Meisch yep actually even better.

Answer (score 1):

The methods that you need to put this together are readily available on the String and Character classes.

Here is an example program that does what you are looking for:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // First try null and the empty string
        System.out.println(isValidPhoneNumber(null));
        System.out.println(isValidPhoneNumber(""));
        // Now try an otherwise valid string that doesn't have the right first character
        System.out.println(isValidPhoneNumber("01234567"));
        // Now try an invalid string
        System.out.println(isValidPhoneNumber("9a934581"));
        // Finally a valid number
        System.out.println(isValidPhoneNumber("94934581"));
    }

    static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phoneNo) {
        // First validate that the phone number is not null and has a length of 8
        if (null == phoneNo || phoneNo.length() != 8) {
            return false;
        }
        // Next check the first character of the string to make sure it's an 8 or 9
        if (phoneNo.charAt(0) != '8' && phoneNo.charAt(0) != '9') {
            return false;
        }
        // Now verify that each character of the string is a digit
        for (char c : phoneNo.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                // One of the characters is not a digit (e.g. 0-9)
                return false;
            }
        }
        // At this point you know it is valid
        return true;
    }
}
```

The output it produces is:

```
false
false
false
false
true
```

The final for-each loop could avoid re-checking the first character by using a for loop with an explicit counter, but the performance gain of not checking a single int doesn't outweigh the cleaner code and better readability of the for each construct.

Edit: also please note that I removed the validation error messages from the original question for better readability as the OP asked to explain what the code was doing.

Comment: You removed the validation error messages from the OP's code. You don't think that these are important?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I think that validation error messages are absolutely important! The OP was asking for working code and to explain what it did and I was simply trying to keep it concise for better readability. I'll add a note to that affect in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the first character of the `phoneNo`:

```
if (phoneNo.charAt(0) != '9' && phoneNo.charAt(0) != '8') {
    // the first character is not a 9 or an 8
}
```

Documentation for [`charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html%23charAt(int)) from Oracle.

Comment: It posts an error. saying ` The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String `

Comment: Just make sure the phoneNo isn't null or the empty string first.

Comment: @mohanram, ask another question on SO. It isn't productive to answer in the comments. Or better, Google it.

Comment: @ejp fixed the logic. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking the phone number in a Integer variable take it in a String variable.
Then check whether the 1st number is 9, 8 or not by using stringVariable.charAt(0)

and for length of the phone number use int len=stringVariable.length();